# How to access an environment variable that I defined from the last successful build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to access an environment variable that I defined in the job 'A' from another job 'B'

job 'A' defines it by -

```
evn.upload_loaction = "loc"
```

In job B I am trying to access the last successful build of JOb A and get that variable -

```
        def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("deploy-artifact-pipeline")
        def dev_deployed_build=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
        def envVars= dev_deployed_build.getEnvVars()
        echo envVars['upload_loaction']   // prints null
        echo envVars['BUILD_NUMBER'] // prints 21
```

My custom variable is not recognized but generic ones like build_number is available.

When I trigger Job A as downstream job then I can access using -

```
def jLz = build (job: 'deploy-artifact-pipeline')
echo jLz.buildVariables.PROCESSOR_UPLOAD_LOCATION // prints loc
```

Can someone help me with this? Or is there a better way to store and access that variable from a previous build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnvInject plugin and Pipeline job doesn't go hand in hand, if some environment variable needs to be stored I usually prefer that job to be a free style job where you can send your env variable to be stored at the end of the build and that can be accessed for the specific build with "injectedEnvVars/api/json"

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach that I handled was to create an artifact file with the required information. And in the other Jenkins pipeline I download the artifact file and read the information in it.